# Subtracting an interval from max(date) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have run queries of this sort in postgreSQL and it works:

```
Select max(date_hour) - interval '2 days' from table
```

I tried the same in MySQL and also a few permutations and combinations i.e. by removing 's' from days and removing quotes and also tried using 'date_sub' but, it didn't work. Does anything of this sort work in MySQL? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The SQL standard would be `interval '2' day`, not `'2 days'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select max(date_hour) - interval 2 day 
from your_table
```